# Screen flashes when iTunes is open

Tags: display, itunes, flashing

Has anyone had an issue with your computer screen flashing when iTunes is open? This started about one week ago. This only happens in iTunes and I am on version 12.3.2.35. iI so, is there a fix?

Comment: It could be graphics issue. I used to have that on a different application... Does this happen with any other application?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a fairly common situation that popped up with the latest iTunes update (12.3.2.35), with no fix yet from Apple.  See [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7375794?tstart=0) and [this other thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29492010#29492010) on Apple Support Communities. Evidence suggests that the issue is independent of the version of Windows and not specific to any one graphics chipset. The flashing occurs only when displaying the iTunes Store.  All other parts of iTunes are fine.

The current workaround is to downgrade to [version 12.3.1.23](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-6562#versions) and wait for Apple to fix the problem. I have done this myself and am not seeing any flashing after the downgrade to 12.3.1.23.

I'll update this answer once there is a working version released.

**UPDATE:** It seems your milage may vary. On one of my machines, the downgrade worked and the display is now rock solid.  On another, there's still flashing happening, although it seems to be less often.  Let's hope Apple can get to the bottom of this and get a fix out soon.